# Security Headers in .htaccess Not Working in EasyApache4/Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0

Tags: linux, .htaccess, security, http-headers, apache2.4

Good afternoon from the UK,

We are having a few issues at the moment with our security headers and could do with some awesome advice like we always get.

We have recently updated our server to Apache 2.4 with EasyApache4 and upgraded PHP to version 7. Our previous mod_headers in our .htaccess file no longer work and we need to get it back on track.

The code is below if you can help?

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOWALL
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
    Header always set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I did differently was to not use `mod_headers`and to enclose each option in double-quotes.

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOWALL"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"
Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
```

You can check these settings and more at https://securityheaders.io/. A sister site, https://report-uri.io/, offers support with Content-Security-Policy settings and reports.

Answer (score 0):

There are use of security headers to in php code to open `.htaccess` file and paste below code to solve all issues. please use this code also in wordpress `.htaccess` files.

```
# Security Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    # Header set Content-Security-Policy ...
    Header set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
    Header set Feature-Policy "geolocation 'self'; vibrate 'none'"
    Header always set Permissions-Policy: "accelerometer=(self), autoplay=(self), camera=(self), document-domain=(self), encrypted-media=(self), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(self), gyroscope=(self), magnetometer=(self), microphone=(self), midi=(self), payment=(self), picture-in-picture=(self), sync-xhr=(self), usb=(self)"
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
</IfModule>
```